# Converting Epoch time format to standard time format

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having an issue with converting the Epoch time format `1585542406929` into the 2020-09-14 Hours Minutes Seconds format.

I tried running this, but it gives me an error

```
from datetime import datetime

DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

datetime.utcfromtimestamp(df2.timestamp_ms).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

```
error : cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

What am I not understanding about this datetime function? Is there a better function that I should be using?

edit: should mention that timestamp_ms is my column from my dataframe called df.

Comment: `datetime.utcfromtimestamp` works with _one_ integer value. I'm guessing that `df2.timestamp_ms` is a series (_many_ integer values), so of course this function won't work with them

Comment: What is ``df2.timestamp_ms``? How does JSON come into play here?

Comment: Just wrote an edit to make sure it's known that timestamp_ms is my column in my dataframe df. Is there a function that will re-format an entire column of time stamps?

Comment: Even as an integer, 1585542406929 represents a time too far in the future to represent. Divide it by 1000 first to get a number of *seconds*, rather than *milliseconds*, to convert. (Though if you do that, you get a timestamp from March 30, 2020. If it's *supposed* to represent a timestamp on Sept 14, it's not clear what the format actually is.)

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, that number is really just the number of seconds...but starting when? 01/01/00 AD?

Comment: @bosois, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: @ForceBru Interpreting ``1585542406929`` as a seconds since the epoch corresponds to Wed Nov  3 07:22:09 in the year 52213. That does not seem reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @chepner for helping me understand the format that this is in.

A quick solution is the following:

```
# make a new column with Unix time as @ForceBru mentioned

start_date = '1970-01-01'

df3['helper'] = pd.to_datetime(start_date)


# convert your column of JSON dates / numbers to days 

df3['timestamp_ms'] = df3['timestamp_ms'].apply(lambda x: (((x/1000)/60)/60/24))


# add a day adder column

df3['time_added'] = pd.to_timedelta(df3['timestamp_ms'],'d')

# add the two columns together

df3['actual_time'] = df3['helper'] + df3['time_added']
```

Note that you might have to subtract some time off from the actual time stamp. For instance, I had sent my message at 10: 40 am today when it is central time (mid west USA), but the timestamp was putting it at 3:40 pm today.